How to solve error while installing php-gd on oracle linux 7 for php 7.4
Trying to install php-gd on Oracle Linux 7 with php7.4.
sudo yum update
sudo yum install php-gd

Any of the above command generates below error:
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:7.4.33-15.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.33-15.el7.remi for package: php-gd-7.4.33-15.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.103()(64bit) for package: php-gd-7.4.33-15.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gd3php.x86_64 0:2.3.3-7.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libraqm.so.0()(64bit) for package: gd3php-2.3.3-7.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.7()(64bit) for package: gd3php-2.3.3-7.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:7.4.33-8.el7.remi will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.33-8.el7.remi for package: php-xml-7.4.33-8.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.33-8.el7.remi for package: php-sodium-7.4.33-8.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.33-8.el7.remi for package: php-7.4.33-8.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.33-8.el7.remi for package: php-json-7.4.33-8.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.33-8.el7.remi for package: php-cli-7.4.33-8.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.33-8.el7.remi for package: php-pdo-7.4.33-8.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:7.4.33-15.el7.remi will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libraqm.x86_64 0:0.7.0-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package libwebp7.x86_64 0:1.0.3-2.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package php.x86_64 0:7.4.33-8.el7.remi will be updated
---> Package php.x86_64 0:7.4.33-15.el7.remi will be an update
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:7.4.33-8.el7.remi will be updated
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:7.4.33-15.el7.remi will be an update
---> Package php-json.x86_64 0:7.4.33-8.el7.remi will be updated
---> Package php-json.x86_64 0:7.4.33-15.el7.remi will be an update
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:7.4.33-8.el7.remi will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 7.4.33-8.el7.remi for package: php-oci8-7.4.33-8.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:7.4.33-15.el7.remi will be an update
---> Package php-sodium.x86_64 0:7.4.33-8.el7.remi will be updated
---> Package php-sodium.x86_64 0:7.4.33-15.el7.remi will be an update
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:7.4.33-8.el7.remi will be updated
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:7.4.33-15.el7.remi will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-oci8.x86_64 0:7.4.33-8.el7.remi will be updated
---> Package php-oci8.x86_64 0:7.4.33-15.el7.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libclntsh.so.21.1()(64bit) for package: php-oci8-7.4.33-15.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-oci8-7.4.33-15.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
           Requires: libclntsh.so.21.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Followed all the instructions above, nothing works. Tried these --skip-broken
and rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest command but no luck.

First, remember that Enterprise Linux 7 have reached its end of life in June.
So this distribution is unmaintained and insecure.

Requires: libclntsh.so.21.1()(64bit)

See https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues/167
So you need to install the RPM of Oracle Instant Client version 21 to be able to install the RPM of php-oci8
P.S. The current version of Oracle Instant Client is 23, used by new builds for maintained distributions (EL-8 and EL-9).

Already have installed oracle instant client 21.6 installed. Even php-oci8 is also installed. But whenever I run sudo yum update or sudo yum install php-gd this error appeares.

I don't see anything about php-gd in your paste, please post full command, and full output

update with full output.

So, same answer, the only error is about "libclntsh.so.21.", so Oracle Instant Client RPM is NOT installed (see link in my answer)

how can I verify? I followed this link. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lacli/install-instant-client-using-zip.html#GUID-D3DCB4FB-D3CA-4C25-BE48-3A1FB5A22E84

You cannot use the ZIP, you need the RPM.
